# Обработка нажатия на оповещение

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на оповещение с определенным текстом открывалась определенная вкладка viewPager, но как это реализовать?

```
private void showNotification(String title, String body) {
        int a = new Random().nextInt();

        array.add(a);

        resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyFragment.class);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(page.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(body)
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        notification = builder.build();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(a, notification);

        list.add(b+":"+a);
        System.out.println("Notification "+list);


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить action:

private void showNotification(String title, String body) {
        int a = new Random().nextInt();

```
    array.add(a);

    resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyFragment.class);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(page.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
    resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    builder.addAction(
        R.drawable.ic_icon,
        "open",
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 
            requestCode,
            Intent(this, YourActivity.class).putExtra(YourEnum.PAGE_STRING.getName(), yourPage), 
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
    )

    notification = builder.build();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(a, notification);

    list.add(b+":"+a);
    System.out.println("Notification "+list);
}
```

Идея следующего характера, вы в нотификашку добавляете [PendingIntent](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/204-urok-119-pendingintent-flagi-requestcode-alarmmanager.html), в него добавляете интент с вашей активностью и добавляете ту страницу, которую необходимо открыть, а в активности ловите данный интент, и открываете нужную страницу. Создаёте слушателя и через него устанавливаете нужную страницу. Внимание, там есть три разных слушателя, зависит от версии ViewPager:

```
val listener = object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
   override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
        }

        override fun onPageScrolled(
            position: Int,
            positionOffset: Float,
            positionOffsetPixels: Int
        ) {
        }

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            )
        }
    }
}

onCreate {
  val page = intent.getStringExtra(YourEnum.PAGE_STRING.getName())

  viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerListener)

//после настройки и установки адаптера (тоесть добавления данных в адаптер) и вызова adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), если после изменения адаптера не вызовете и будете устанавливать страницу, получите креш
  listener.onPageSelected(page) //учитывайте что страницы идут с нуля, если выше не учтено, используйте page-1. Установку страницы я например делаю в коллбеке, который добавляет данные в адаптер
}
```

P.S. Ссори, давно не делал на джаве, потому Котлин. Тут ничего нет страшного, разберётесь

Answer (score 0):

Это не совсем то, что Вам надо, но все же, оставлю, вдруг надо будет потом.
При нажатии на оповещение открывается приложение, а точнее MainActivity.
Можно вписать этот код в начальный класс

```
                if (intent.extras != null) {

                for (id in intent.extras!!.keySet()) {

                    val id_value = intent.extras!!.get(id)

                    if (id.equals("id")) {

                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, CurrentNews::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("id", id_value.toString())
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Вы отправляете оповещение с текстом news и id конкретной новости, к примеру. При нажатии по оповещению открывается приложение. Получаем news + id и открываем конкретную активити. Можно создать новую активити (такую же, как фрагмент, который Вам нужен), и при запуске заполнить его данными. Или же вставить в него фрагмент, который во ViewPager.